# scrape using xpath and domdocuments

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, html-parsing

I am learning how to scrape data from websites but I got stuck on this one.I can't post the link here due to privacy issues but i will try to explain.

Rating for hotel 1:

```
<div class = "right">
    <div data-res-id = "305281" class = "tooltip rating-for-305281 rating-div left res-snippet-small-rating level-6">
                                           3.5
                 </div>
```

Rating for hotel 2:

```
<div class = "right">
    <div data-res-id = "8913" class = "tooltip rating-for-8913 rating-div left res-snippet-small-rating level-7">
                                           3.9
                 </div>
```

Rating for hotel 3:

```
<div class = "right">
    <div data-res-id = "4959" class = "tooltip rating-for-4959 rating-div left res-snippet-small-rating level-8">
                                           4.2
                 </div>
```

Like this there are 100's of hotel each with different class so I am not able to use xpath or I don't know much about it.

I want to scrape all the ratings i.e. "3.5", "3.9", "4.2"of the restaurants, but problem is that every rating has different class and different id.

Please I am just a beginner and I want to learn things so can anyone tell me how scrape these ratings of the hotel??
If you can give me an example then it would be great..
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an HTML parser, there are multiple choices, but [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is one the simplest to use and understand. Here is an example that gets the text of `div` elements that has `rating-div` class:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <div class = "right">
        <div data-res-id = "305281" class = "tooltip rating-for-305281 rating-div left res-snippet-small-rating level-6">
                                               3.5
                     </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "right">
        <div data-res-id = "8913" class = "tooltip rating-for-8913 rating-div left res-snippet-small-rating level-7">
                                               3.9
                     </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "right">
        <div data-res-id = "4959" class = "tooltip rating-for-4959 rating-div left res-snippet-small-rating level-8">
                                               4.2
                     </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print [r.get_text(strip=True) for r in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'rating-div'})]
```

Prints:

```
[u'3.5', u'3.9', u'4.2']
```

Answer (score 1):

use `lxml` library

this will return list of all `divs` which contain rating.

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html_text = etree.HTML(html.read())
rating_list = html_text.xpath('//*[@class="right"]/div') 
#rating_lst = html_text.xpath('//*[@class="right"]')  # choose accordingly, I dont have full source-code so commented out

for rate in rating_list:
     print rate.xpath('text()')
```

## Code for given sample data

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

data = """
<div>
    <div class = "right">
        <div data-res-id = "305281" class = "tooltip rating-for-305281 rating-div left res-snippet-small-rating level-6">
                                               3.5
                     </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "right">
        <div data-res-id = "8913" class = "tooltip rating-for-8913 rating-div left res-snippet-small-rating level-7">
                                               3.9
                     </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "right">
        <div data-res-id = "4959" class = "tooltip rating-for-4959 rating-div left res-snippet-small-rating level-8">
                                               4.2
                     </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

# html = urllib2.urlopen(url)         #use these two lines if getting source from a url
# html_text = etree.HTML(html.read())  

html_text = etree.HTML(data)
rating_list = html_text.xpath('//*[@class="right"]/div') 

for rate in rating_list:
     print rate.xpath('text()')[0].strip('\n\t ')
```

Comment: How to store these array of ratings in a variable. Like in xpath i do like this: $addressQuery = $xpath->query("//span[@class='search-result-address']/text()");      can you help on this gaurav?